# Data base with do until registration

Tags: database, loops, vb6

So I am struggling right now on how to make my program work in vb6. The function of the command button is when the TLoginR.text has the same text in the database it will display a message box stating "user name is not available...". Now here is the problem, when I type a new text and is not in the database the prompt still pops up. I kindly need for help thanks.

Code:

```
Private Sub CRegR_Click()

   Dim user as string
   Dim pass as string
   Dim prompt as string

   RegR.Refresh
   user = TLoginR.Text
   pass = TPassR.Text

   Do Until Regr.Recordset.EOF
      If RegR.Recordset.Fields("Username").Value = user Then
         prompt = MsgBox("Username not available, please try another one!", vbOKCancel)
         If (prompt = 1) Then
            TLoginR.Text = ""
            TPassR.Text = ""
            Register.show
         Else
         End If
         Exit Sub
      Else
         RegR.Recordset.MoveNext
      End If
   Loop

   RegR.Recordset.Fields("Username").value = user
   RegR.Recordset.Fields("Password").value = pass
   RegR.Recordset.Update
   Register.Hide
   Login.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: You are sure that the 'RegR.Recordset' is retrieving only one record? May be there are multiple records retrieved and the text you are entering is some where in one of the records.

Comment: Yes sir. I just want to verify if the text that is in the TLoginR.text does not have a record under the field of "username", if it exist, a message will prompt stating that "the username is not available...", if not, then it will addnew to the record.

Comment: You need to start doing some basic troubleshooting. Add a debug.Print statement for user before the loop and see if it's what you think it is. Or at least add it to your  msgbox telling user what they attempted to enter. Also debug.print your field.username . finally use constant vbOK instead of 1 for readability when checking prompt response

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make an assumption that your recordset contains every record in the table. I'm also assuming you're protecting against empty user names somewhere else. I suspect you probably have records you don't expect to have because you are not moving your recordset to the first record before you start iterating it. However, that's based on assumptions I'm making because we can't see that code.

```
Private Sub CRegR_Click()

   Dim user As String
   Dim pass As String
   Dim prompt As String

   RegR.Refresh
   user = TLoginR.Text
   pass = TPassR.Text

   RegR.Recordset.MoveFirst 'return to the first record
   Do Until RegR.Recordset.EOF
      If StrComp(RegR.Recordset.Fields("Username").Value, user, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
         prompt = MsgBox("Username not available, please try another one!", vbOKCancel)

         If (prompt = vbOK) Then
            TLoginR.Text = ""
            TPassR.Text = ""
            Register.Show
         Else
            'do domething?
         End If

         Exit Sub
      Else
         RegR.Recordset.MoveNext
      End If
   Loop

   RegR.Recordset.Fields("Username").Value = user
   RegR.Recordset.Fields("Password").Value = pass
   RegR.Recordset.Update
   Register.Hide
   Login.Show

End Sub
```